# How to go about classifying 1000 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-classification

I am trying to find research paper with theory(preferably implementation) that is about classifying 1000 (or more) classes. I have heard of an implementation, that initially clustering needs to be done then classification with something like softmax. Does anyone know of any research paper that implements 1000+ class classification.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking for arbitrary ML task dealing with 1000+ classes the most straigtforward thing that comes to mind is the `ImageNet` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageNet#cite_note-nytimes_2012-2. It has more the 20k categories in the present time.

In order to perform such classification task you need

- A large enough dataset, such that each class occurs frequently enough or efficient data augmentation
- A powerful model, such that can adapt to variety of different problems

The first neural network to tackle this problem was `AlexNet` and since then plethora of architectures : `VGG's`, `ResNet's`, `EfficientNet` got better and better quality.

They have a lot of filters that react on different patterns.